Is stochasticity totally incompatible with current theories of conservation of information in quantum physics?
Most physicists accept the unitarity principle of the universe, according to which the state of a system at any given time must determine its state at any other time (information is never lost, according to the no-hiding theorem). An example of this is the search for potential solutions to the black hole information paradox.
To date, as far as I know, we do not know to what extent this principle (which implies quantum determinism and reversibility) holds, since all proposed solutions contain inconsistencies.
My question for discussion then, is the following:
Are mathematical models of conservation of quantum information fundamentally incompatible with a relatively small level of stochasticity? In the sense that, e.g., the quantum state of A could lead to several possible states: A' (with probability 99%) or A'' (1%), so that the future is unpredictable but the past can be unambiguously reconstructed. Probabilistically determined and reversible.
Is there anything in the mathematics of the current respected theories in quantum physics that is fundamentally incompatible with a certain type of stochasticity in the fundamental laws of the universe?

By Kraus's second representation theorem, even quantum operations that appear random can be represented deterministically on a dilated Hilbert space. For measurements, we just include the state of the apparatus, and all outcomes occur. However, because we are classical, we only experience one outcome, chosen at random. But all quantum dynamics have a deterministic representation. This comes from the axioms and properties of $C^*$-algebras. Is this relevant to your question?


the state of a system at any given time must determine its state at any other time This is not true after quantum measurement; the result of the measurement and the subsequent quantum state after is not determined by the previous state. This is why the measurement problem exists.


@Ján Lalinský correct, but then it is the measurement - and not reality itself - that contains stochastic indeterminacy (due to hidden variables?). The nature of things could still be deterministic or indeterministic. Am I understanding you?
Models still assume determinism, even if this determinism cannot be verified with our current measuring devices. Correct?

@pyring In orthodox quantum theory, "state" means quantum state, e.g. psi function; then determinism works only for a limited time, until the measurement forces the collapse to some eigenstate of the measured quantity; the result of the measurement (and the subsequent state) is random, we only have probabilities for it. In hidden variable theories, we can have determinism all the way. E.g. in Bohmian mechanics, "state" includes positions of all particles, and evolution is determined by the initial conditions (which include initial positions of particles).

Thanks @Ján Lalinský, does this mean that quantum theory -and in particular the measurement problem- is fundamentally incompatible with the unitary principle by which the state of a system at any given time must determine its state at any other time (information is never lost). It seems as if all theories assume determinism, but such determinism cannot be verified.

@pyring description of measurement in orthodox quantum theory is incompatible with linear unitary evolution. Determinism or indeterminism in real world indeed cannot be falsified. We can only check and say whether particular theory is deterministic or not.

In classical physics, measurable quantities such as position are described by variables $\mathbf{r}(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$ that also provide the outcome of a measurement. So if you measure the $x$ position you would get the value $x(t)$.
There are "interpretations" of quantum theory, such as the statistical interpretation or hidden variable interpretations, that claim the theory is stochastic: a system is described by some set of variables that also provides measurement results but we can't predict the result but only the probability of a set of possible results. This is not compatible with the equations of motion of quantum theory but advocates of these interpretations haven't proposed an explicit alternative. There are other stochastic theories that explicitly modify quantum theory such as spontaneous collapse theories
https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.14969
or pilot wave theory
https://arxiv.org/abs/2408.05403
Pilot wave and spontaneous collapse theories don't currently reproduce the predictions of relativistic quantum theories which are the vast bulk of successful predictions of quantum theory:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568
It is unclear what predictions are made by the statistical interpretation because it doesn't give an explicit model of what is happening in reality.
Quantum theory without modifications describes systems in a very different way. The equations of motion for measurable quantities such as position are written in terms of Hermitian operators called observables whose eigenvalues are the possible results of measurements. In general, the evolution of an observable can't be described in terms of it having just a single value over time because of quantum interference. For an example see Section 2 of
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911150
But when information is copied out of a quantum system interference is suppressed: this is called decoherence:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
A measurement is an interaction that produces a record of some property of the measured system. Systems large enough for you to see in everyday life have information copied out of them on scales of space and time much smaller than those over which they change significantly so you don't see much interference in everyday life for the objects you can see.
As a result of this lack of interference this complicated structure described by the observables is divided into layers each of which evolves approximately like the universe as described by classical physics on the scale of everyday life:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.2189
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033
This is often called the many worlds interpretation of quantum theory but it is just an implication of the theory when it is taken seriously as a description of reality. The state of a system in quantum theory describes what observables have been decohered and what their values were and it is a Hermitian operator with unit trace.
Quantum theory doesn't allow you to predict the result you will see when you do an observation because there isn't a single fact of the matter about what you will see. It predicts the expectation values of any observable $\hat{A}$ in terms of the state $\rho$:
$$
\langle\hat{A}\rangle = tr(\rho\hat{A}) = \sum p_ia_i
$$
where the $a_i,p_i$ are the possible outcomes and their probabilities respectively. These probabilities aren't like the probabilities in stochastic theories because they only really make sense when a system has decohered. These probabilities can be explained in terms of symmetries of the quantum state, see:
https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.2718
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0405161
https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.02048
In addition records of the past only exist for observables that have decohered. As a result there are no records below the scales at which decoherence operates:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9902008
The sense in which information is conserved is that the evolution of the observables is unitary. In principle that evolution is time reversible. This doesn't imply that we can control, predict or reverse the evolution of real physical systems except to a limited extent in a lab.

No, there is nothing that is incompatible with even quite a large amount of stochasticity.  There are spontaneous collapse theories of quantum mechanics; see for instance GRW theory:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghirardi%E2%80%93Rimini%E2%80%93Weber_theory
